# React react-router-dom pass props to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need to pass props to component using router.
Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import AppBarTop from './appbar/AppBarTop';

import Login from '../pages/login/Login';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';


class App extends Component {

    render() {

        const { isAuthenticated } = this.props;

        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <AppBarTop isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
                    <div className="content">
                        <Route path="/login" isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} component={Login} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see, isAuthenticated the prop i want to pass to Login component.

```
class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <LoginForm />
        );
    }

}

export default connect(null) (Login);
```

When i log the props the **isAuthenticated** prop is not there. What i'm doing wrong? How can i pass the prop correctly?
I followed the docs and also other discussions. From my understanding it should work.
The version of **react-router** and **react-router-dom** is **4.0.0**

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Pass it like this:

```
<Route 
    path="/login" 
    render={(props) => <Login {...props} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}/>} 
/>
```

It should be available by `this.props.isAuthenticated` in Login Component.

**Reason of `{...props}`:**

If we don't write this then only `isAuthenticated` will get passed to Login component, all other values that router passes to component, will not be available inside Login component. When we write `{...props}` then we are passing all the values with one extra value.

And instead of using `component` with router use `render` method.

As per [DOC](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic):

[**Component**](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component):

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the
>   router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the
>   given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the
>   component attribute, you would create a new component every render.
>   This results in the existing component unmounting and the new
>   component mounting instead of just updating the existing component.
>   When using an inline function for inline rendering, use the render.

[**Render**](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func):

> This allows for convenient inline rendering and wrapping without the
>   undesired remounting.

Comment: I am getting undefined for some reason for the props

Comment: I have it like this: `<Route path="/ShowW" render={(props) => withRouter(<ShowW {...props} isAuthenticated={true}/>)} />`

Comment: I am trying to read it in my `componentDidMount` like this `console.log(this.props.isAuthenticated)`

Comment: you dont need to use withRouter in this case, simply write: `<Route path="/ShowW" render={(props) => <ShowW {...props} isAuthenticated={true} />)} />`