# passing props within react router with history object

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/
import appState from './AppState'

const customHistory = createBrowserHistory()
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route path="/submit" component={Submit} history={history}/>
    </div>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Notice:
if I add appState like other properties; 

there is not property such as appState in Submit component,

if I use this;

```
<Route path="/submit" render={routeProps=> <Submit appState={appState}/> history={history}/>
```

appState pass fine but this time history object is missing, what is proper way of doing this?
appState is just mobx class instance.

EDITED: I found a "weird" solution. i changed route element to this;

```
 <Route path="/submit" render={routeProps=> <Submit appState={appState}/> history={history}/>
```

then I am able to access same history object via `this._reactInternalInstance._context.router.history.push('/home')`
before I made this change i was able to use it as `this.props.history.push('/home')`

if I leave this as it works fine but its annoying getting this history object with this way

Comment: You should pass `history` object to `router`, not to `route`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Maybe in common yeah but in this sample I am able to use it like "this.props.history.pushState('/previousPage')" so my issue is not cover wit useage of history

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469071/react-react-router-dom-pass-props-to-component/43469277#43469277

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's right, better for you to put the history in Router not Route.

See below answer, this one work well on me. You still can use `history.push` in this answer. Sometimes `history.push` didn't redirect the page. if this happen to you, you can put `location.href = location.href` to refresh the page.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42679052/7765396

Comment: hi, thanks for answer but as I mention in comment section thats got nothing with my issue here,

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong, I'm sure in it. Browser history is a singleton object, so you can export it from module. Look here:

```
//history.js:
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/
export default createBrowserHistory();

//Submit.js
import history from "myapp/history"
export default class Submit extends React.Component {
   ...
}

//MyRouter.js
import Submit from './myapp/Submit'
import appState from './AppState'
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route path="/submit" component={Submit}/>
    </div>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: yeah actually I suppose to use customHistory(instance of createBrowserHistory), that was all about the issue here :D