# Passing props to nested routes in React Router 4. TypeError: render is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create nested routes like this, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43469277/1800515) SO answer

```
/--Home
|--campaigns
   |--campaigns/:cid
```

Index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
    ,
    document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Home foo="bar" {...props}/>}/>
          <Route path="/campaigns" render={(props) => <Campaigns foo="bar" {...props}/>}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Home.js

```
const Home = () => (
    <div>
        Home
    </div>
)
```

Campaigns.js

```
const Campaigns = () => (
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/campaigns" render={<div>Campaigns</div>}/>
        <Route path="/campaigns/:cid" render={(props) => <Campaign {...props} foo="bar"/>}/>
    </div>
)
```

Campaign.js

```
const Campaign = () => (
    <div>
        <Route path="/campaigns/:cid" render={<div>Campaign 1</div>}/>
    </div>
)
```

I'm using the  method since I cannot use the  method to pass props to the component.

While the / route is working fine, when I browse to /campaigns I get: TypeError: render is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explanatory. The `render` prop accepts a function as its value, not elements. So just change it to:

```
const Campaigns = () => (
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/campaigns" render={() => <div>Campaigns</div>}/>
        <Route path="/campaigns/:cid" render={(props) => <Campaign {...props} foo="bar"/>}/>
    </div>
);

const Campaign = () => (
    <div>
        <Route path="/campaigns/:cid" render={() => <div>Campaign 1</div>}/>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I understood what the error message was saying perfectly and I swear I looked at this nine ways to Sunday and I've no idea how I wasted almost 5 hours looking for this. I must be sleep deprived.