# How to use url params in separate component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've been learning React over the last 2 days, and I'm having trouble with understanding URL parameters.

Let's say I want a route `mysite.com/details/1023`. The route is defined like:

```
<Route path="/details/:id" render={() => <DishDetails />}/>
```

Now I want the `DishDetails` object, which is defined in another file, to be able to use the `id` value `1023`. How can I do this? I've found tutorials on route url params but none that explains how to achieve this.

Here's what my `DishDetails` view looks like right now:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import "./DishDetails.css";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

class DishDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: /*url param*/,
        };
    }
    render() {
        return this.state.id;
    }
}

export default DishDetails;
```

Where can I get the `id` in DishDetails? I've tried:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import "./DishDetails.css";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

class DishDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: match.id,
        };
    }
    render() {
        return this.state.id;
    }
}
```

But `match` is undefined.

Comment: `id: props.match.id`?

Comment: Nope, `props.match` is undefined as well...

Comment: you are not passing the props to component, that's why its not available, use this: `<Route path="/details/:id" render={(props) => <DishDetails {...props} />}/>`, now it will be available by `this.props.match.params.id`, check this answer for more details, [**LINK**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469071/react-react-router-dom-pass-props-to-component/43469277#43469277)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your component to `Route` via the component props:

```
<Route path="/details/:id" component={DishDetails} />
```

If you did this `match` is available in the props.

If you have to keep the way how you render your routes you can pass the render props manually to your component:

```
<Route path="/details/:id" render={(props) => <DishDetails {...props} />}/>
```

You can find the whole documentation for react-router [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route).

Comment: Thanks! In the second example, what is actually passed through `props`? The props of the class containing the Routes?

Comment: These are the route props which `Route` pass to the component/render function/... It's in the [doucmentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props).

Comment: hey you should pass down just match

Comment: "If you did this match is available in the props." This functionality must have been a recent change as it's not available in the version of react-router I'm using.

Comment: @Andy I'm using and running the latest version. And it's documented: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component

Comment: cant you do `render={(props) => <DishDetails match={props.match} />}` so you arent passing down history and all the other props that arent needed.

Comment: @Omar: sure, that is possible. I gave the example where you pass all props because it matches the behavior of easier solution `component`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`<Route render>`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#route-render-methods) prop receives the [router props](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#route-props):

- `match`
- `location`
- `history`

You need to provide that props to the `<DishDetails>` component and use the `match.params.id` to retrieve the `id` from your `path="/details/:id"`

```
const DishDetails = props => <div>Details Id: {props.match.params.id}</div>;

<Route path="/details/:id" render={props => <DishDetails {...props} />} />
```

This is the **Route props** in your example:

```
{
    match: { path: '/details/:id', url: '/details/1', isExact: true, params: { id: '1' } },
    location: { pathname: '/details/1', search: '', hash: '' },
    history: { length: 3, action: 'POP', location: { pathname: '/details/1', search: '', hash: '' } }
}
```

---

> There are 3 ways to render something with a `<Route>`:
>
> - `<Route component>`
> - `<Route render>`
> - `<Route children>`

Read more [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#route)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the `withRouter` function that comes with react-router?

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

class App extends Component {
   .... your stuff
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

That should give you access to the "match" prop

Comment: If you use a HOC here you add to much overhead. Instead he should use the `component` prop of `Route`.