# React Router don't pass value to match.props

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So, I started learning React with Redux and react-router. Big mess for a .net

I want to use the `match` object to find the props in a given url, so I can do this:

```
function NumberHeader ({match}){
   var number = match.props.nr;
   ..... Logic down here ...
}
```

I defined a route like this:

```
<Route path={`/number/:nr`} component={() => <NumberHeader match={this.props.match} />} />
```

The `NumberHeader` component is rendering at right url, but I can't get any props.

All this logic is happening not in the App root, it's happening in this rendered componen:

```
<Route path={routes.NUMERO} component={() => <DrawsPage />} />
```

What are the key factors that I need to folow, so this will work? I'm using the latest react-router v4. Thanks.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Passing props to component in react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469071/react-react-router-dom-pass-props-to-component/43469277#43469277)

Comment: Do you only need match to get "nr" url parameter? Then whey are you bothering passing "match" as a prop to the component. This is unnecessary. You can get it easily via `match.params.nr` from NumberHeader component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the props from the component declaration:

```
component={props => <NumberHeader {...props} />}
```

Alternatively, just do

```
component={NumberHeader}
```